# Is the modded Skyrim play time inclusive of unmodded Skyrim play time?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, pc

I've been playing *Skyrim SE* recently and I wanted to see my total modded and unmodded playtime. So I'm trying to see the time played when loading a character. It says I've played 58 hours on the unmodded save and 106 hours on the modded save.
So does the 106 hours on the modded save include the 58 on the unmodded save? I personally think it doesn't because it also shows 6 mins as a prisoner at the start of the game separately.

Comment: Sorry, but how can we possibly know that? First of all: where did you get those playtimes? Are they of the same or of different characters? And I think you already have your answer, because the full intro as 'Prisoner' [takes less than 6 minutes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8RnyEnUZIqg).

Comment: @Joachim: You're still "Prisoner" while you have the character creation menu open, since you don't pick a new name until you finalize your appearance. I'm not sure if it counts that time. It arguably *shouldn't* because the game is paused, but I have never paid much attention to the statistics menu so I have no idea whether Bethesda thought of that.

Comment: @Kevin That's a very good point! I think it does count as playing time. Playing time usually still counts when the game is paused, because it usually counts the time the time a program is running (here with the added condition that you're in-game as a character, not just in the main menu, but that can be verified through Steam, if playing through that).

Comment: @Joachim When you open the game, click on load and you'll see your saves. Click on a save and you'll see some number in this format : 109.11.15. 109 is the number of hours, 11 the number of minutes and 15 the number of seconds of played as that character.

Comment: @Zohair Thanks, I know, it just wasn't clear from your post :) If you had used a different tool, that would have been important.

Answer (score 1):

If they're the same character: yes. Otherwise, no.

The same rules still applies for even if you multiverse time travel, save scum, etc.

Unless you have a mod that modifies your playtime stat, just having mods alone will not affect the functions that govern the playtime counter...

As for Steam's counter: That's a seperate thing altogether.

Comment: Yes they are the same character.  and thanks!